# Symfony2: Get form default values before validation

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I use Silex and Symfony2 Form component. I try to get default values from the form object on first entry on the page, so before the form is sent by the user. I try to do it like that:

`$query = $form->getData();`

But it is empty until the form is sent. On the other hand this works:

`$form->get('searchRadius')->getData()`

And it shows default values. Is it possible to make the getData() method work without sending the form? Or is there any other method to get default values from the form I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My question is not clear enough so I will try to fix it.

I have a controller. In this controller I create a form with some default values. Now I try to get those values using `$form->getData()` but it returns nothing. On the other hand when I try to access its children (i.e. form fields) and ask for data like `$form->get('searchRadius')->getData()` it does return default value. But I want to avoid asking every child separately to get the default value. I want to ask the form as it was sent.

I would like to do something like the following in a controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm();
$defaultValues = $form->getData();
```

Thank you for your time and tips.

Comment: I ended up creating form from entities. This way Symfony will prefill data automatically. I say that is the correct way to create forms in Symfony and my first idea with deafault values wasn't good! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you handle current request by form? Try to handle request first and then check is form valid:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$data = $form->getData();
var_dump($data['searchRadius']);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Yes I am handling request and then validating the form. My question is how can I "// do something..." without validating form and/or handling a request. The form has default values and I want to use them to "// do something..."

Comment: @greg But before you handle the request - your form must contain default value and you can use it, isn't you?

Comment: That is the problem. I cannot use those values from getData() before I handle the request.

Comment: @greg Are you try to dump the data that returned with `getData()` or dump whole form to find place where store your default data?

Comment: Yeah. Object is too big to dump and getData() returns nothing. I will have to dig in code of Form object I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with default values for the form. But in Symfony you can create your forms in the server and then display them in the web page. See the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) If you do that, you can assign the values to the form's fields as you want.

On the other hand, if you are creating your forms directly into the html, the server doesn't know about them until they are submitted. In this case, the server only sees the variables and their values, depending on what was sent. So if you had an input text with some value assigned in the html, and the user changed it, you will not be able to retrieve it from the form (unless you start creating extra hidden fields with this "defaults" values).

Comment: I am creating a form in a controller, and few lines lower I try to access its default values (which I defined with formbuilder).

Comment: Could you post your code? Are you using the same controller to create and handle the form? If that is the case, your problem is probably that you are trying to get the data from the submitted form and in that case, the server only knows the pair variable:value.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you don't have to use `$form->getData();` to get your entity/model objects. You can first instantiate them and then pass them into the form object, like so:

```
$formType = new \My\Bundle\Form\Type\SomeType();
$formModel = new \My\Bundle\Form\Model\SomeModel();
$form = $this->createForm($formType, $formModel);
```

You can access the properties of your entity/model by using the object's getters, like so:

```
$formModel->getSomeProperty();
```

It's not clear what you're struggling with in your example above, but all the `$form` object does is simplify rendering and validation of forms.

Note: In your example above, `$form->getData();` and `$form->get('searchRadius')->getData();` are not the same thing. The latter is a child of the former, so it's one level down (ie a nested form).

Comment: I understand that it is a child of a form object. That is why I do not undestand why using $form->getData() gives no results back (since asking its children does bring results).

Comment: Can you post the code in your controller where you create your form and the details of the form you are trying to instantiate? Looking at the edits you added, `$form = $this->createForm();` is not correct syntax. You need to pass at least a string (representing a service with the form.tag element) or an object implementing the FormTypeInterface.  From the API, here's the function definition for the createForm method: `public Form createForm(string|FormTypeInterface $type, mixed $data = null, array $options = array())`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to generate some default values for the case when the user initiates a get 
request and enters the form submission view for the first time.

In this case you have to provide some DEFAULT VALUES for the form - here is a simple example:

```
$app->get('/form', function() use ($app) {

// default data for the form !!!
$defaultData = array(
    'name' => 'Your name',
    'email' => 'Your email'
);

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $defaultData)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('email')
    ->add('password')
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(1 => 'male', 2 => 'female'),
        'expanded' => true
    ))
    ->getForm();

$rootGetData = print_r($form->getData(), true);
$nameGetData = print_r($form->get('name')->getData(), true);
$passwordGetData = print_r($form->get('password')->getData(), true);

return new Response('root form data is:<pre>' . $rootGetData . '</pre>' 
    . 'name form data is:<pre>' . $nameGetData . '</pre>'
    . 'password form data is:<pre>' . $passwordGetData . '</pre>');
});
```

Here is the result I get in the browser:

```
root form data is:
Array
(
    [name] => Your name
    [email] => Your email
)
name form data is:
Your name
password form data is:
                                               !!! NO VALUE FOR PASSWORD !!!
```

So when creating a Form (some object implementing the **Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface**) you always have to provide some default data. Notice that your way of getting the data with `$form->get('password')->getData()` does not work in the example. I did not get any results. That's because when we created the form we did not pass any value for the password property. You should make sure you pass your default values properly to use `getData()`.

Form object are usually created by either a **FormFactory** or a **FormBuilder**. If you check out the methods that create the actual form instance, there is always a `mixed $data = null` parameter present. In case of the *FormBuilder* the data is passed with the method `createBuilder` (as in the example above).

Actually this is almost the same example as in the [silex form documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html)

Comment: Thx for long and detailed answer. Default values are already defined. What I try to achive is to get them using $form->getData() method. But it returns nothing until I handle request and/or validate the form.

Comment: Hmmm that's really strange. Can you share some more details about how you create your form?